# change Angular Material checkbox color

Tags: angular-material

I'm using Angular material. I need to change the color of header checkbox after selecting any checkbox from row. see the below screenshot.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZzgj.png)

I used Angular Material and I'm only expecting the change the color of header checkbox after checking any rows checkbox.

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="select">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
        <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null" [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
            [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
        <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()" (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
            [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </td>
</ng-container>

<ng-container matColumnDef="bcNumber">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> BC # </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        {{element.bcNumber}}
    </td>
</ng-container>

<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? What exactly is NOT working in your solution? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your issue. Also, please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can add an attribute "color" in checkbox
for example:

```
<mat-checkbox class="example-margin" [checked]="allComplete" [color]="primary" [indeterminate]="someComplete()"
    (change)="setAll($event.checked)">
    {{task.name}}
</mat-checkbox>
```

If you want the upper checkbox to be consistent with the color below, you can use

```
[color]="primary"
```

Comment: With the square brackets syntax, there must be a variable with the name `primary`, which holds the desired color. This seems a little weird in this case. I think you are looking for the regular attribute syntax where the value is interpreted as string: `color="primary"`